# Possible to access WMI through ADO?

Tags: wmi, oledb, ado, wbem

Is there an OLEDB provider for WMI/WBEM?

In other words, could someone access WMI through:

- ADO in shell vbscript
- ADO in ASP script
- ADO in Win32 native process
- SQL Server linked server
- SQL Server OPENROWSET()

Is there an OLEDB provider for WMI/WBEM?

Is it possible to access WMI through ADO?

---

i hear rumors that an ODBC driver exists for WMI, but i cannot see it installed on my machine. Plus, i'm asking about OLEDB (and ADO that wraps it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: *No*

There used to be an ODBC WMI adapter for Windows 2000 Server as an optional installation. ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384736(VS.85).aspx)). It is not supported on later Windows versions ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392726(VS.85).aspx#odbc_adapter)).

Comment: i edited your question to include the answer of *no*; and marked it as answered. You get credit because you were in first.

Answer (score 0):

It would be too much work to wrap every class in WMI to OLDEB tables. Number of WMI classes exploded in the XP/2003 timeframe. If you are only focusing on certain classes, you can [write your own OLEDB provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h63swas7(VS.80).aspx) that calls WMI and returns the data.